# navigator.push does not navigate to the next screen

Tags: navigation, stack-navigator

I am sorry, but why is navigator not navigating to the next screen after signing in the user? I barely got the FB signin working.

```
    switch (result.status) {
  case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    final FacebookAccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken;
    _showMessage('Logged in!')
     
    goToMainScreen(context);

    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    _showMessage('Login cancelled by the user.');
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
    _showMessage('Something went wrong with the login process.\n'
        'Here\'s the error Facebook gave us: ${result.errorMessage}');
    break;
}
}

   void goToMainScreen(BuildContext context) {
Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TabScreen()));
 }
}
```